# pdf text extraction

Tags: pdf, text, extract

```
3 begincidrange 
<20> <7e> 1 
<8140> <817e> 633 
<8180> <81ac> 696 
endcidrange
```

This is a CMAP file sample.

1. How do I make a CMAP for my own data ?
2. What is 3 in 3 begincidrange
3. what is <20> <7e>? can anyone give an example

Comment: the 3 is the number of lines in the range. No idea about the rest though.

Answer (score 2):

Your CMap table establishes all of the character code to CID mappings.

The number that appears before the begincidrange operator indicates the number of mapping
lines. The endcidrange operator terminates a block of mappings.

The lines in between begincidrange and endcidrange contain the mappings. There are 3 entries for each line. The first two specify the character code range and the 3rd is the CID value they map to.

So character codes 0x20 to 0x7e map to CID 1.

Adobe Technote 5099 describes the format for CID tables.

Comment: This is not exactly correct. The mappings in the `range` sections actually specify contiguous mappings, so 0x20 to 0x7e map to multiple CIDs in the range 1 to 95 (since 0x7e - 0x20 is 94 decimal). This is indeed mentioned in the [spec](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/font/pdfs/5099.CMapResources.pdf).